# Using html within Quarto

Tags: html, rstudio, quarto

I am trying to build a simple website using Quarto and I would like to know how to use html within the Quarto.

I would like to create a page which is divided in two equal parts. On the left there would be only .gif element as a background. On the right, there would be a text with a button below which could be used as a link.

I try to use the following code in index.qmd file but it doesn't work.

```
---
title: ""
---
---
format: html
---
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; height: 100vh;">
<div style="flex: 1; background: url('gif_example.gif') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
</div>
    
<div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
<p>To jest napis na prawej stronie</p>
<button>Przycisk</button>
</div>
</body>
```

I am using Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
---
title: ""
format: html
---

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; height: 100vh;">
<div style="flex: 1; background: url('gif_example.gif') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
</div>
    
<div style="flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
<p>To jest napis na prawej stronie</p>
<button>Przycisk</button>
</div>
</body>
```